# Justify text with leading whitespace

Tags: formatting, textwidth

To justify text on vim I use `:set textwidth=77` and `space+v` to select and finally `gq` to justify the text.

This is the result

original:

```
   Most of the command-line options that you can use with GCC are useful for C programs; when an option is only useful with another language (usually C++), the explanation says so
   explicitly.  If the description for a particular option does not mention a source language, you can use that option with all supported languages.
```

"justified"

```
       Most of the command-line options that you can use with GCC are useful
for C programs; when an option is only useful with another language (usually
C++), the explanation says so explicitly.  If the description for a
particular option does not mention a source language, you can use that option
with all supported languages.
```

I want a text like this

```
Most of the command-line options that you can use with GCC are useful
for C programs; when an option is only useful with another language (
usually C++), the explanation says so explicitly.  If the description
for a particular option does not mention a source language, you can u
se that option with all supported languages.
```

Is possible with vim without using external tools like fmt?

Comment: Is the text originally in one line? Do you have leading space?

Comment: Is copied from man gcc inserted in text with r ! man gcc

Comment: But the double space is in the original text you can remove it with `:'<,'>s/ \+/ /` but this not justification it is edition ;-)

Comment: Right I correct my question

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :-)

Comment: I took the liberty of rephrasing the question's title. Words like "Vim" and "question" really don't carry much information when asking a *question* on *Vim* SE :-) Feel free to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
:set tw=77
```

`gg`<kbd>Shift v</kbd>`G` to select the text,

`:left` to kill the leading spaces,

`gv` to restore the selection,

`gq` to wrap the text.

Comment: Is a little better but in the line "If the description for a particular" retain two white spaces, I put the result in my question now

Comment: The first operation (<) could as well be `:%<`

Comment: `ggVG<` or `gg<G` will only remove one level of indentation, *i.e.*, remove `'shiftwidth'` number of spaces. To remove *all* leading whitespace, it's better to use `:%left`.